# Android Google Sign In, Keeps Failing

Tags: android, google-play-services

So there's lots of questions on this, and seemingly lots of (somewhat contradictory) documentation.

I'm simply trying to get a user to sign in to submit a score to a Google Play Services leaderboard in my app.

So they press "show leaderboard" and I begin the sign-in checking process:

```
public void displayLeaderboard()
{
    if (checkPlayServices() == true)
    {
        // First, sign in.
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

        if (account == null)
        {
            // Need to get sign-in client?
            if (_googleSignInClient == null)
            {
                // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
                GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build();
                _googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
            }

            Intent signInIntent = _googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, CALLBACK_SIGN_IN_TO_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT);
        }
        else
        {
            actualDisplayLeaderboard(account);
        }
    }
}
```

---

So then onActivityResult() **does** catch the callback, so far so good:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CALLBACK_SIGN_IN_TO_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT)
    {
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent()
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try
        {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
        // THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS
        // **********************

            // Signed in successfully.
            // ...
        }
        catch (ApiException e)
        {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            System.out.println("Failed to sign in.");
            String message = e.getMessage();
            System.out.println(message);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

As indicated above, that is where it fails.

```
12-10 17:24:54.877 12571-12571/*.*.* W/System.err: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12501: 
12-10 17:24:54.877 12571-12571/*.*.* W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source)
12-10 17:24:54.877 12571-12571/*.*.* W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source)
12-10 17:24:54.887 12571-12571/org.fortheloss.sticknodespro W/System.err:     at *.*.*.AndroidLauncher.onActivityResult(AndroidLauncher.java:1013)
```

Looking at the samples for signing in and leaderboards, my code looks identical.

I feel like I'm going astray with all the Firebase console and/or Google Play Services console (who knows anymore, it's such a mess) OAUTH and SHA-1 stuff I don't know what I need, what I don't need, it's all over the place and it still doesn't work. Some things are for a "web application" - this isn't a web application - I have the credentials there anyway, put in the app, etc - doesn't matter, still doesn't work.

Any pointing in the right direction appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In typical fashion, the answer comes about after posting the question

This is the fix

```
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id)).requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE).build();
```

Where `R.string.server_client_id` is as described here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get_your_backend_servers_oauth_20_client_id

(At first, the page it brought me to was for another version of my app, so when I was using that credential, it obviously wasn't working. Then, I realized I needed to create a release build (with my release keystore) to get it to work.)

Things the sample projects fail to show/mention ^

They doesn't even use `requestIdToken(...)`

EDIT: And the reason...that it doesn't use requestIDToken, despite it being used in nearly every similar StackOverflow answer, is because you're not supposed to. For Android applications. This is because you're supposed to have this in the Android Manifest (app_id taken from Google Play Services console linked app section)

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Would be GREAT if Google Play Services would yell at you if you didn't have those included...